# Possible orders of products of 2 involutions which interchange disjoint residue classes of the integers

Tags: gr.group-theory, nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, permutation-groups, computational-group-theory

### Definition / Question

**Definition:** Let $r(m)$ denote the residue class $r+m\mathbb{Z}$, where
$0 \leq r < m$.
Given disjoint residue classes $r_1(m_1)$ and $r_2(m_2)$, let the *class transposition*
$\tau_{r_1(m_1),r_2(m_2)}$ be the permutation of $\mathbb{Z}$ which interchanges
$r_1+km_1$ and $r_2+km_2$ for every $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ and which fixes everything else.

> **Question:** Which integers occur as orders of products of 2 class transpositions?

**Added on Dec 8, 2013:** The question whether it is true that
only finitely many integers occur as orders of products of two class
transpositions will appear as Problem 18.48 in:

Kourovka Notebook: *Unsolved Problems in Group Theory*. Editors V. D.
Mazurov, E. I. Khukhro. 18th Edition, Novosibirsk 2014.

### Known results

The known finite orders of products of 2 class transpositions are the divisors of 60
except for 5, as well as 8, 24, 40, 42, 84, 120, 168 and 420. I do not know whether
there are further, or even only whether there are finitely or infinitely many.

Among the 409965 unordered pairs of distinct class transpositions which interchange
residue classes with moduli $\leq 12$, there are

- 179470 whose product has order 6,
- 83298 whose product has order 12,
- 60208 whose product has order $\infty$,
- 38818 whose product has order 2,
- 14127 whose product has order 3,
- 13491 whose product has order 4,
- 10407 whose product has order 60,
- 8918 whose product has order 30,
- 976 whose product has order 20,
- 218 whose product has order 10,
- 32 whose product has order 15, and
- 2 whose product has order 8.

The orders 24, 40, 42, 84, 120, 168 and 420 appear to be still more "seldom",
and occur only for products of class transpositions which interchange residue
classes with larger moduli.

### Remarks / Background

1. I asked this question on the [Nikolaus Conference 2012](http://www.math.rwth-aachen.de/Nikolaus2012/index.html) in Aachen.
   In response, [Michael Cuntz](https://www.iazd.uni-hannover.de/cuntz.html) found some possible orders which were not known
   to me at that time (namely 8, 24 and 42).
   Afterwards, a more systematic search by myself revealed the further possible
   orders 40, 84, 120, 168 and 420. The question though remains open.
2. Some products of 2 class transpositions have infinite order, but the length
   of the longest cycle which intersects nontrivially with a set $\{1, \dots, n\}$
   grows only logarithmically with $n$. This may fool the naive approach of
   estimating the order by taking a number of cycles and computing the
   least common multiple of their lengths.
3. The set of all class transpositions of $\mathbb{Z}$ generates the infinite
   simple group discussed in the article

   [A simple group generated by involutions interchanging residue classes of the integers](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s00209-009-0497-8).
   *Math. Z.* 264 (2010), no. 4, 927-938. ([PDF](https://stefan-kohl.github.io/articles/simplegp.pdf)).

### Examples

Minimal examples for the known orders are as follows ("minimal" means in
this context that the maximum of the moduli of the involved residue classes
is the smallest possible):

- Order $\infty$: $\tau_{0(2),1(4)} \cdot \tau_{0(2),1(2)}$
- Order 2: $\tau_{0(4),1(4)} \cdot \tau_{2(4),3(4)}$
- Order 3: $\tau_{0(3),1(3)} \cdot \tau_{0(3),2(3)}$
- Order 4: $\tau_{0(3),1(3)} \cdot \tau_{0(2),1(2)}$
- Order 6: $\tau_{0(3),2(3)} \cdot \tau_{0(2),1(2)}$
- Order 8: $\tau_{0(2),5(6)} \cdot \tau_{2(9),8(9)}$
- Order 10: $\tau_{1(2),2(4)} \cdot \tau_{0(3),4(6)}$
- Order 12: $\tau_{1(4),3(4)} \cdot \tau_{1(3),2(3)}$
- Order 15: $\tau_{0(3),2(3)} \cdot \tau_{0(2),1(4)}$
- Order 20: $\tau_{1(4),3(4)} \cdot \tau_{0(3),1(6)}$
- Order 24: $\tau_{0(3),1(6)} \cdot \tau_{1(8),19(20)}$
- Order 30: $\tau_{0(3),1(3)} \cdot \tau_{0(2),3(4)}$
- Order 40: $\tau_{0(10),3(15)} \cdot \tau_{2(4),12(24)}$
- Order 42: $\tau_{0(4),9(10)} \cdot \tau_{0(3),4(15)}$
- Order 60: $\tau_{3(4),4(6)} \cdot \tau_{1(5),2(5)}$
- Order 84: $\tau_{0(8),6(20)} \cdot \tau_{0(3),26(30)}$
- Order 120: $\tau_{0(4),10(24)} \cdot \tau_{1(15),10(30)}$
- Order 168: $\tau_{0(8),6(20)} \cdot \tau_{2(3),6(30)}$
- Order 420: $\tau_{0(8),6(20)} \cdot \tau_{6(15),26(30)}$

The [GAP](http://www.gap-system.org/) package [RCWA](http://www.gap-system.org/Packages/rcwa.html) contains

- a database of pairs of class transpositions which interchange
  residue classes with moduli $\leq 32$ and whose product has finite order
  not dividing 60, i.e. the "seldom" ones -- see [here](https://stefan-kohl.github.io/rcwa/etc/ctprods32.g) (162KB), and
- a database of all 409965 pairs of class transpositions which interchange
  residue classes with moduli $\leq 12$, sorted by the order of their product --
  see [here](https://stefan-kohl.github.io/rcwa/etc/ctprods12_uncompressed.g) (18MB).

Comment: Could you give some examples with order $15$?

Comment: Examples with order 15 are e.g. $\tau_{0(3),2(3)} \cdot \tau_{0(2),1(4)}$,
$\tau_{2(3),1(6)} \cdot \tau_{1(4),3(8)}$ and $\tau_{5(6),8(12)} \cdot \tau_{2(9),8(9)}$.


Comment: Is there a nice expanation for why 5 is not seen as an order in small examples? Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2013.05.06

Comment: @Gerhard: at least none that I know.

Comment: four of the "seldom" orders, 24, 84, 168, 420, are yielded by a pair with $(m_1,m_2) =(8,20)$. Is that a coincidence or rather just a pair you have chosen in your search? Maybe searching with (8,28) or (12,20) and some random numbers for the rest yields more orders? or (9,15)? just a suggestion into the blue...

Comment: @Wolfgang: I think it is not really just "a coincidence", but so far I haven't been able to use it to find pairs yielding further orders. In any case by far not all pairs with orders 24, 84, 168 or 420 have $(m_1,m_2) = (8,20)$ -- there are many others as well. -- E.g. $\tau_{3(4),13(24)} \cdot \tau_{1(25),19(30)}$: order 24,
$\tau_{0(3),1(30)} \cdot \tau_{11(20),5(32)}$: order 84, 
$\tau_{1(5),4(30)} \cdot \tau_{10(12),20(32)}$: order 168,
$\tau_{0(15),10(30)} \cdot \tau_{10(20),28(32)}$: order 420.

Comment: sure. And I suppose you have noticed that in many (but not all, see the 120 one) of the examples for seldom orders, there is one pair where $m_1$ does **not** divide $m_2$ (or vice versa). No idea if that can tell us anything. Have you found examples also for some others of the seldom orders where for each pair one divides the other? and are there pairs of seldom order where in **both** factors the $m_i$ do not divide?

Comment: @Wolfgang: Order 24, both divide: $\tau_{0(3),11(18)} \cdot \tau_{3(4),9(28)}$
Orders 84, 168, 420: I don't know any where both moduli divide
(but it is quite possible that, enlarging the search bounds,
one would find some).
Order 24, none divide: $\tau_{0(6),10(15)} \cdot \tau_{6(8),0(20)}$.
Order 84, none divide: $\tau_{0(8),6(20)} \cdot \tau_{2(9),6(30)}$.
Order 168, none divide: $\tau_{0(25),17(30)} \cdot \tau_{11(12),21(32)}$.
Orders 120 and 420, none divide: I don't know any example so far.